# search and find several keys in array

Tags: php, arrays

```
public function array_searchh($needle, $haystack) {
    foreach ($haystack as $key => $value) {
        $current_key = '';
        $current_key .= $key;
        if ($needle === $value OR (is_array($value) && $this->array_searchh($needle, $value) !== false)) {
            return $current_key;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

When I search in array return first key, but I want to search and if there same value return all keys.

```
[0] => Array ([id] => 1[value] => payamm)
[1] => Array ([id] =>2[value]=>payam)
[2] => Array ([id] => 25[value] => payam)
[3] => Array ([id] => 3[value] => payam)
[4] => Array ([id] => 4[value] => payam)
[5] => Array ([id] => 5[value] => 340)
```

In above array, I have several "payam" values. When I use above function, I just return the first (found) key but I want all matching keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public function array_searchh($needle, $haystack) {
    foreach ($haystack as $key => $value) {
        $current_key = '';
        $current_key .= $key;
        if ($needle === $value OR (is_array($value) && $this->array_searchh($needle, $value) !== false)) {
            $foundKeys[] = $current_key;
        }
    }
    if (isset($foundKeys)) {
        return $foundKeys;
    }
    return false;
}
```

This should return an array of all the found keys.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of immediately returning the key, collect all matching keys into an array and return this array at the end of the function.

```
public function array_searchh($needle, $haystack) {
    $returnKeys = array();
    foreach ($haystack as $key => $value) {
        $current_key = '';
        $current_key .= $key;
        if ($needle === $value OR (is_array($value) && $this->array_searchh($needle, $value) !== false)) {
            $returnKeys[] = $current_key;
        }
    }
    return (count($returnKeys) > 0) ? $returnKeys : false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe the [array_keys()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) function would help?